# How to transfer html between two liferay input editors?

Tags: javascript, liferay

I have two liferay input editors in a form. On a button click I need to transfer the html from the first input editor to the second.

I have tried with javascript and names attribute but I cant get it to work.

How is the proper way of doing this?

```
<liferay-ui:input-editor name="firstEditor"/>

<liferay-ui:input-editor name="secondEditor"/>

<button onClick="moveInfo()"></button>

<script>
function <portlet:namespace />initEditor() {
    return '';
}

function moveInfo(){
    //Code missing
}
</script>
```

Comment: Type `CKEDITOR.instances.firstEditor.getData()` in console, what do you see?

Comment: This were one of the solutions I tried before posting and it didnt work. I thought I didnt need <portlet:namespace /> since I dont use it in the "name" attribute. But now it worked when I added the <portlet:namespace /> but not without it. The solution that worked for me: CKEDITOR.instances.<portlet:namespace />firstEditor.getData() and then just use setData() as well. Thank you!

Comment: You will require to add `<portlet:namespace />` as `<liferay-ui:input-editor>` will append unique portlet identifier (namespace) before its elements. Well, post your solution as answer, so that it may be useful for others in future.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer would be:

```
var value = CKEDITOR.instances.<portlet:namespace />firstEditor.getData();

CKEDITOR.instances.<portlet:namespace />SecondEditor.setData(value);
```